# Google Places Autocomplete: list cities and multiple languages

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm working on a site where I'm using Google Places autocomplete to get the user's city. But I'm stuck with two things:

- Even when I restrict the search by country and city, I still get street names as a result. Is there any way you can list just cities?
- Is a multilanguage site, so if the user enters "Seville" or "Sevilla" I should get the same place id. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

use the country restriction for the same

```
function initialize() { var options = { types: ['(cities)'],  componentRestrictions: {country: "us"} }; var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField'); var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can get only cities or only countries.You can get all that data whatever language you want.
Here is a link where has correct documentation and some examples.
http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/places-autocomplete.html